# Nginx `$remote_addr` always returns `127.0.0.1` only

Tags: nginx

My workflow is as follows.
**[ Client => Kubernetes Service => Nginx => Tomcat ]**

Here's my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $http_nid_id [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # HTTP server
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name localhost;

        set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
        real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive  on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
...
...
```

When API is called, `$remote_addr` is displayed as `127.0.0.1` in `access.log`.
Here's my access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2021:21:32:25 +0900] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2021:21:32:25 +0900] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2021:21:32:25 +0900] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2021:21:32:27 +0900] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 98 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
...
```

Why is `$remote_addr` `127.0.0.1`?
(Ref. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_addr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `set_real_ip_from` to `127.0.0.1`, so as docs says in [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)
, it makes client address `127.0.0.1`

Just omit this line for getting real client address

Comment: The line was removed, but the same result was `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Where your requests are coming from actually ? @henry-jo

Comment: I request it from my local MacOS terminal. `$curl http://[Kubernetes Service IP]/test`

Comment: So you are requesting from localhost then your ip is 127.0.0.1. What's wrong with that ? @henry-jo

Comment: Nginx is not working in my Mac local machine. The nginx is operating in a container. Why is 127.0.0.1 normal?

Comment: $request_addr is ip of requester, and you are requesting from 127.0.0.1, so nginx shows you this ip. It's not ip of where nginx is serving @henry-jo

Answer (score 1):

You has set ‍`X-Real-IP` when proxying the queries. In tomcat just use getHeader("x_real_ip") to obtain the real IP of the client.